# Infected squares warmup: infect a 7x7 board with 21 squares

Tags: geometry, combinatorics, cellular-automata

You can consider this a "warmup" to my [other question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118925/79453) about infected squares.

On a $7\times7$ square, some cells are infected; if a cell shares an *edge* with $3$ infected squares, it becomes infected. Show that we can infect the whole square with only $21$ initially infected cells.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
>  XOXOXOX
>  OXOOOXO
>  XOXOXOX
>  OOOXOOO
>  XOXOXOX
>  OXOOOXO
>  XOXOXOX
> ```

X is infected. O is not.

Comment: Perfect! This is the unique solution. (As a bonus: how many do you think you need for 15x15?)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger is it 85? I would guess it's the solution of this one from each corner, plus a single one in the center

Comment: @Ivo Indeed it is. This generalizes to give the (unique!) optimal solution for board sizes one less than a power of two.

Comment: Proof of optimality:  The value (2*Infected area + perimeter) is a monovariant.  (Stays same when an empty surrounded by three infecteds becomes infected; shrinks if an empty surrounded by four infecteds becomes infected.)  Less than 21 infected has a smaller value than the target position.